# Image not showing even though file path is correct

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Im trying to load in a picture that was uploaded into the wwwroot path. I then save the filepath into the database and retrieve it to show it in my view.

Saved file:
https://pasteboard.co/IeMBH07.png

The filepath thats in ViewBag.Photo : `"C:\\Users\\Me\\source\\repos\\Trinity SOLID\\Trinity\\wwwroot\\Billie.jpg"`

The filepath in the view Img src :C:\Users\Me\source\repos\Trinity SOLID\Trinity\wwwroot\Billie.jpg

View

```
<h1>match</h1>

<img src="@ViewBag.Photo" alt="Profile" />
<br />
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult LoadPotentialMatch()
        {
            string stringID = Request.Cookies["UserID"];
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(stringID);
            logicmatch.TrulyPotentialMatchesList(ID);

            string value = Convert.ToString(logicmatch.pmatchID);
            SetCookie("pmatchID", value, 10);

            ViewBag.FirstName = logicmatch.FirstName;
            ViewBag.Age = logicmatch.Age;
            ViewBag.Bio = logicmatch.Bio;
            ViewBag.Sex = logicmatch.Sex;
            ViewBag.Photo = logicmatch.Photo;
            return View("match", "Matching");
        }
```

Comment: are you sure you are using app.UseStaticFiles(); in your startup class in Configure method ?? Please refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Please look at my answer here on how to serve uploaded files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402266/upload-photos-in-wwroot-and-do-not-load-their-urls/54406157#54406157

Comment: It is possible that your path has changed when you run your application. Use a MapPath to get the full path to your directory _pathToBillie = Server.MapPath("wwwroot/Billie.jpg");

Comment: @AntonToshik I have added a picture to show that the pictures are being uploaded correctly

Comment: @JanneckLange I added a picture so you can see how it was saved